# Парсер Jsoup, массив

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Доброго времени суток. Требуется спарсить статьи с сайта и затем вывести в `ListView`. Пытаюсь спарсить несколько статей с сайта при помощи `Jsoup` и затем записать его в массив `arr` для дальнейшего вывода в `ListView` но где то допускаю ошибку, выбивает NPE. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text;
    Button button;
    Parser par;
    String text3;
    int i = 1;
    ArrayList arr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                par = new Parser();
                par.execute();
            }
        });
    }


    class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.anekdot.ws/page/2").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements text2 = doc.select("div.entry-content");
                ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Element temp : text2) {
                    arr.add(temp.text());
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView.setText(arr.get(3));

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылочку на сайт можно?

Comment: @jessez, обновил первый пост. на нем тренировался

Comment: Странно, у меня всё работает и никаких ошибок нет

Comment: @jessez, привел полный код. может я где то выше в коде не так что-то определил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к пустой ссылке arr, вот и кидает ошибку.
Должно быть так `Element arr[] = new Element[50];`
Где 50 - количество ячеек массива.
Может лучше воспользоваться каким-либо контейнером? ArrayList к примеру.

Крэшится потому, что Вы все равно не создаете массив. Создайте его там же, где создаете ссылку, т.е. в теле класса. В методе вы создаете совсем другую ссылку и другой массив, к которому метод doInBackground обратиться не может, т.к. созданный массив находится в области метода (читаем про Java: область видимости), а массив который находится в области класса (т.е. в теле класса) объявлен так и не был.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text;
    Button button;
    Parser par;
    String text3;
    int i = 0;
    Element arr[] = new Element[10];
```

Но лучше использовать ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Element> elementsList = new ArrayList<>():
```

Добавлять элементы можно методом add(Element e);

```
elementsList.add(temp);
```

Вытаскивать методом get(int index);

```
elementsList.get(3).text();
```

UPD:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text;
    Button button;
    Parser par;
    String text3;
    int i = 1;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                par = new Parser();
                par.execute();
            }
        });
    }


    class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.anekdot.ws/page/2").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements text2 = doc.select("div.entry-content");
                for (Element temp : text2) {
                    arr.add(temp.text());
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView.setText(arr.get(3));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Забываю, что массивы надо инициализировать... Добавил в `onCreate()` `Element arr[] = new Element[10];`, все равно крашится, после нажатия на кнопку =( Знаю, что `ArrayList` динамичен и получше для этого дела будет, но моих знаний пока не хватает с ним совладать. Если Вас не затруднит на данном примере помочь с использованием `ArrayList` буду очень Вам благодарен.

Comment: Обновил сообщение

Comment: Обновил код в соответствии с Вашими рекомендациями (первый пост): объявил в главном классе `ArrayList arr;`, инициализировал его `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();` в `doInBackground`. По идее вроде как на выходе в `arr` должен получаться массив строк `String` и без проблем выводиться в `textView`, но в `setText` выбивает ошибку (прикрепил скриншот, первый пост). Пробовал дописать `textView.setText(arr.get(3).toString());`, ошибка пропадает, но крашит после нажатия на кнопку (в логе NPE ссылается на эту строку).

Comment: Обновил сообщение, вы опять же ссылку ArrayList arr оставляли пустой. Нужно либо сделать так, как я написал в сообщении, либо в методе `arr = new ArrayList<>();`, а не `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();` - так вы создаете абсолютно новый контейнер, который никакого отношения не имеет к тому контейнеру, к которому обращается метод `onPostExecute(Void result);`

Comment: Большое спасибо, за подробные разъяснения.